# How do I see/browse a list of versions/properties/etc of azure Resources?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-resource-manager

Azure APIs are constantly changing and it is extremely hard to follow - while the documentation is perpetually behind.  They recently published a very useful tool at https://resources.azure.com but that only shows the version they want to you see at the time?

Does anyone know a way I can simply browse the API, or a simple list of versions I can look at.  It is beyond frustrating to try and dig through the documentation as you never know with version it even references.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: +1. This is one of my biggest frustration with Azure - REST API documentation is either missing or not kept up to date. At some places, it is grossly incorrect. May I know if you're looking for something in specific. Having worked with Azure Resource Manager REST API for past few months quite extensively, I have come up with some workarounds. I can share those if I know about the specific things you're looking for.

Comment: resources.azure.com will always only show the versions which are in production for all the services. So expecting older versions on this is not the right expectation. can you elaborate which services older version docs you are looking for?

Comment: do you just want to see all the apiVersions for all the providers?  The /providers API will give you that, also you can run "azure provider list --json" from the CLI and you can dump that to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official and the most complete Azure Resource Manager (ARM) resources schemas, api versions and properties are available at the GitHub link below.

[Azure Resource Manager Schemas - GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-resource-manager-schemas/tree/master/schemas)

Alternatively, you can also browse to [Azure Quickstart templated](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/templates/) to search for the resources you want to provision and refer to the latest templates available for what should be the api version and properties to be used.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed!  Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Is this acceptable as an answer to you?